# Transferring large amount of money into a bank account for spouse visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

If the financial requirement for the spouse visa sponsor is 18,600 GBP a year, does it matter if my bank statement have an overdraft every month of the 6 months I am issuing the statement for?

And is there a problem if my father transfers the visa fees into my account? The only requirement is that you earn 18,600 GBP and I couldn't find any restriction for having an overdraft or transferring a large amount of money before applying?

Comment: I was thinking "large amount of money" and "visa fees" did seem a bit weird, but wooooo... That's not a cheap visa! £1033 per person from within the UK...

Comment: @jcaron applying from outside UK and it will cost around 3200 GBP including fees, NHS and priority service

Comment: Never transfer large amount of money for visa. it is a red flag.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Not true at all for long term UK visas. As long as the transfer can be explained, it is possibly to meet the extortionate fees with someone else's help. This is not a case of trying to make finances look better than they actually are.

Comment: You may want to read this article on funds parking: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications

Comment: @RoboKaren This is not relevant to long term visa applications. Applicants aren't assessed for ties to their home country. If savings are used to meet the financial requirement, then it is permitted to use gifts, as long as the funds are under the control of the applicant or sponsor for 6 months prior to application. The providence can be investigated, but as long as a coherent explanation is provided, it will not cause a problem.

Comment: @MJeffryes the funds must be demonstrably legitimate, however.  If another party gives a large sum of money to the applicant, the applicant must show that the other party acquired the money legitimately, which will at least imply submitting the other party's bank statements with the application.

Comment: What level of overdraft are you talking about? IANAL but it might be a concern to UKVI if, for example, your statements show you are in financial difficulties and can not support yourself.